# How do I run these assembly programs on Win 7 cygwin 64

Tags: assembly, windows-7, cygwin, nasm

I have a windows 7 64 bit, and I have installed nasm, cygwin64 and set the path variables. I went to dr. paulcarter's assembly language tutorials and downloaded his sample programs (cygwin). I opened cygwin went to the directory where the sample programs are and executed the following instruction

```
$nasm -f win32 array1.asm -o array1.o
```

and I was taken back to the command prompt
here I wrote

```
$ ld -m elf_i386 -s -o array1 array1.o
```

and I got this

```
"ld: unrecognised emulation mode: elf_i386
Supported emulations: i386pep i386pe"
```

How can I make these and later my own programs work?

Comment: "elf" is for Linux. For Windows try one of the other modes.

Comment: What other mode? can you please suggest? I need a specific command

Comment: As the error message states: `i386pep` or `i386pe` instead of `elf_i386`. "pe" stands for the PE-format of Windows.

Comment: I'm wondering about using parameters with 386 if the goal is to produce 64 bit programs. An alternative is to use Visual Studio Express, which is free, and use ml64.exe (requires a custom build step in the project).

Comment: @rcgldr: None of [Dr. Paul Carter's](http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/) examples are for 64-bit-mode. Thus one has to build 32-bit executables even on a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: @rkhb - ok, I wasn't sure, since a 64 bit system was mentioned.

Comment: @rkhb So are you saying that I use cygwin 32? I need specific ways to to do this